# Are there any implementations of computability logic?

Tags: computability, logic

I'm currently looking into [Japridze's computability logic](http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~japaridz/CL/). It looks great, but I was wondering whether any programming languages or systems implement it.

Does anyone know of any implementation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any implementations of it in any current programming languages. It is rather new (introduced in 2003), so that may be a factor.

The author does define some "systems" that implement it, which are listed in the [Wikipedia references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computability_logic#Literature). For example, [*Introduction to clarithmetic I*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0890540111001076), and a few related articles.

> “Clarithmetic” is a generic name for formal number theories similar to Peano arithmetic, but based on computability logic instead of the more traditional classical or intuitionistic logics. Formulas of clarithmetical theories represent interactive computational problems, and their “truth” is understood as existence of an algorithmic solution. Imposing various complexity constraints on such solutions yields various versions of clarithmetic. The present paper introduces a system of clarithmetic for polynomial time computability, which is shown to be sound and complete. Sound in the sense that every theorem T of the system represents an interactive number-theoretic computational problem with a polynomial time solution and, furthermore, such a solution can be efficiently extracted from a proof of T. And complete in the sense that every interactive number-theoretic problem with a polynomial time solution is represented by some theorem T of the system. The paper is written in a semitutorial style and targets readers with no prior familiarity with computability logic.

[GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=%22computability+logic%22&type=Code) doesn't reveal anything either.